# $\sin x/x$ uncertainty at $x=0$, and some confusions

Tags: special-relativity, differentiation, mathematics

Think about the function; $$\sin(x)\over x$$  We say frequently at $x=0$ this function is in a uncertain form $0\over 0$. But we conclude $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{sin(x)}{x}=1$$Then we say the function have no value at $x=0$ but only a limiting value at $x=0$. Hence we also say that function has a discontinuity at $x=0$ because the function's limit value is not equal to its function value at $x=0$ (at $x=0$ the function's value is uncertain).

Next i want to discuss this problem in physical viewpoint. We all know about the Fresnel diffraction law. This law states that: $$I(\theta)=I(0)\frac{sin(\beta)}{\beta}$$ Where $I(\theta)$ is the intensity of light at $\theta$ and $\beta=\beta(\theta)$. So my problem is if this function is not described at $\beta=0$ how we can say there is a bright valance at there? Another example is the Einstein's energy formula: $$E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ For light we again have a similar situation: $$lim_{m\to 0,v\to c}\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$ So, is there not a defined energy for light? Absolutely there is! The only solution to this mad question can be that when we are working in Newton's viewpoint, or in calculus world, we can't say just you can't divide to $0$ or $\frac{0}{0}$ is a undetermined form bla bla bla. Actualy
$\frac{0}{0}$ is just the $\frac{dy}{dx}$, in our example $\frac{d(sinx)}{dx}$ and i can say it is equals to  $cosx$ , then at x=0 it has the value 1! But that is the L'Hopital rule! Otherwise we can't say there is a velocity or acceleration because all of theme are actually $\frac{0}{0}$. I need help.

For clarity: Think about the function $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$ at $x=1$ we have $\frac{0}{0}$ uncertainty again. But $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}$=$\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}$=$x+1$ and its value at$x=1$ is $2$. That two function is equal but one of them is uncertain at $x=1$ while second is not. And the $lim_{x\to 1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=2$ too. So first of the functions has a value at $x=1$ but we just don't know what is it before limiting or manipulations. Hence there was no uncertainity at $x=1$ and the function was continuously from the beginning.

Edit: There is an assumption that the obtained function is continuous, so the limit at that point must be the same with the value at that point at physics viewpoint. **Problem has been solved.**

Comment: For the relativity one, $E=\gamma mc^2$ simply does not apply to light.

Comment: $0$ is a removable singularity in many of the cases above.

Comment: $$\text{sinc}(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\text{   for  } x\neq 0,\\
1 \text{   for  } x=0
\end{cases}$$ is a perfectly well-defined and continuous function.

Comment: Mathematically it is true but that formula has beed derived so we can't assume that the function is $1$ at $x=0$. @Photon

Comment: But does it make a difference to nature, if our mathematical language enforces us to make an extra definition for the case $x=0$? You could define the sinc in terms of its Taylor series as well, which would need no definition by cases. The question relevant to physics is: Is the limit $x\to 0$ well-defined or not? In the case of the sinc it is (which is not self-evident! but it is true in the case of the sinc), so everything is fine.

Comment: You are right and you are the one who is closest to my problem.  My question actually  was in some uncertainties we can say limiting value is the actual value of the function at that point. Than there is no uncertainty, discontinuity at all. Derivatives is uncertain things for example $\frac{0}{0}$. @Photon

Comment: Sorry, I don't get your last comment, could you please rephrase it?

Comment: I say if we have $\frac{0}{0}$ uncertainty in a problem, than can we say it has a value at there but we don't know what is it and obtain that value with limit as Newton did when he invented calculus for derivatives. @Photon

Comment: Well, we can calculate this limit by whatever means we want to use, if the limit is well-defined, we are fine to define it to be the function's value at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The derivation of $E=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}}$ starts from $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$ and assumes $m\ne 0$. Alternatively, one could derive $mc^2=E\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$ for any $m$. In the case of Fresnel diffraction, you can derive $I(\beta)=I(0)\mathrm{sinc}\beta$ (if you define that function as $1$ at $0$ so it's everywhere continuous) by handling the $\beta=0$ and $\beta\ne 0$ cases separately. These two cases aren't all that similar, but in both cases what's happened is you've looked at a result that's easy to derive if some quantity is nonzero and misunderstood the details of how that quantity being zero affects the argument.

Comment: That derivation starts from the  $\int vdp$ and second's derivation start from the four momentum. Then we obtain $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$ by putting first obtained energy formula to zero momentum vector in four dimension. And in the case of Fresnel diffraction we can't just say okay, let's put 1 to the  $\theta =0$ , it is a derived formula.

Comment: And if we solve the problem for $\theta=0$ for that problem how can we be sure that the second solution will give us the first solutions limiting value?

Answer (score 0):

I am not too concerned about the sinc function; one can always use the famous formula:

$$ {\mathrm{sinc}(x)} \equiv \frac{\sin{\pi x}}{\pi x}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)},$$

where I've use the so-called normalized sinc function.

Regarding special relativity, there is a treatment (Thorne & Blanford) where proper time $\tau$ is replaced by the affine parameter:

$$\zeta \equiv \tau/m $$

so that the four momentum is the mass times the four-velocity:

$$ p_{\mu} = mu_{\mu} =m\frac{dx_{\mu}}{d\tau}=\frac{dx_{\mu}}{d\zeta}. $$

Taking the limit $m \rightarrow 0$ and $d\tau \rightarrow 0$, while holding $d\zeta = d\tau/m$ finite allows you to do:

$$ p^2 = m^2 $$

without any infinities.